# How can I view Wi-Fi connection history?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-network, logging, history

I want to view wi-fi connection history on my Android phone. Specifically, I want to know which networks the phones was connected to & disconnected from & when.

Edit: My phone is a Nexus 5x (OS is flexible) but I'm interested in this answer for any phone/OS that there's a solution to.

Comment: I've tried "adb logcat -v threadtime ConnectivityService:* *s" but am not quite getting what I'm looking for

Comment: To my knowledge, Android does not log any of that information outside of the normal logcat, if you are not getting the information you need from there, you likely won't get it.

Comment: I may be getting the correct information from logcat, but it's dumping so much data that I can't find what I'm looking for. Any suggestions? I tried searching for the wifi connection name that I connected to in the logs but didn't get any results.